# Add class via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

I have a #myDiv And i want, when page load, ad class to `#myDiv`

E.G. Page load, `#myDiv.class`

I use this code but it's not working:

```
$('#sky').addClass(‘animate-in’);
```

Comment: `‘` is not a quotation mark. Use either `'` or `"`. Also make sure that you run your code after the DOM was loaded. Please have a look at the jQuery tutorial: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(document).ready(function(){` is called whn the doucument is ready. 
and your `addClass` .. use single or double quotes to enclose the class ( **not ‘** )..

try this...

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
   $('#sky').addClass('animate-in'); 
});
```

**UPDATED**

another div

```
<div id="anotherdiv"></div>
```

call the `click` function and the jquery selector to which u want to change the class

```
$('#anotherdiv').click(function(){
    $('#sky').addClass('animate-in');  //or any other new class
});
```

go thorugh the selector jquery documentation..

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Thank you, it's working! Well, how can i add class to sky, when click another div?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `single` or double `quote` to enclose your class.

Change

```
$('#sky').addClass(‘animate-in’);
```

To

```
$('#sky').addClass('animate-in');
```

or

```
$('#sky').addClass("animate-in");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
$(function () {
   $('#sky').addClass('animate-in'); 
});
```

OR

```
$(function () {
    $('#sky').addClass("animate-in"); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
   <body onload='$("sky").addClass("animate-in")' >
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check that already any classes are available in $("#sky") and if u want to use only 'animate-in',

Can try this,

```
$("#sky").attr('class','');

$("#sky").addClass('animate-in');
```

so that we can come to know that, already existing things are cleared and adding a new one